# How to understand the solutions of a 4x4 linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was solving a 4x4 linear equation given by;

2x+y+3z+w = 4

4x+y+4z = 1

6x+2y+7z+w = 5

2x+z-w = -3

When solving, I got that it have 2 free variables associated and 2 leading variables.
What do this mean? What do the solution set form? A space, a line? I dont know how to interpret the solution set.

Comment: You can think about freedom degrees as directions (linealy independent) you add to your solution.
If you have $0$ freedom degree then the solution is unique and geometrically is a point (in this case in $\mathbb{R}^4$.
If you have $1$ freedom degree then the solution is geometrically a line. You can think that fixed 3 variables (for example $x,y,z$) then this define a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ The if you let "move" the variable $w$ you obtain a line.
If you have 2 freedom degrees then geometrically the solution lives in a plane. Now fixed 2 variables you can "move" the others two and obtain a l

Comment: What do you mean at the end? "Now set 2 variables you can "move" the other two and get a l"

Also, thank you. This led me to a different perspective of the solution set. What I got is that, in this case I can define a vector with the two leading variables. Then, by the fact that I have 2 variables of freedom I can move it in two ways, which makes it possible for it to move in a plane.

Comment: That is the right geometrically point of view. I think the page limit my answer.

In generally is always like this. If you are solving a $n \times n$ system of **linear equations**, and obtain $k$ fredoom degrees then the solution live in a **linear space** of dimension $k$.

Comment: Thank you. Helped me a lot to discover this geometrically point of view!

Answer (score 0):

Your space is 4-dimensional (four variables). Your solution set is a 2-dimensional affine subspace, because you have two free variables. It is a two-dimensional "slice" in 4-dimensional space. It does not go through the origin, because your system is not homogeneous.

Comment: By refering to it as a two-dimensional "slice" in 4-dimensional space, can you think in the solution as a plane?

Comment: Sort of. A one-dimensional "slice" in 3D is a line, while a 2-dimensional one is a plane. In 4-dimensional space, you have slices of dimensions 1 (lines), 2, 3 and 4 (the last one is the whole space). All these slices are "flat".